# Blazor Webassembly API Call Children could not be evaluated

Tags: c#, api, rest, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to call an existing rest API I have with my new Blazor Webassembly app, however when I make the call I always get the error **Children could not be evaluated**. The API hits the breakpoint and when I step through it returns the data successfully which I can also see if I call it in postman, however the Blazor call fails. I thought perhaps it was an issue with mismatching classes, however the class structure for TeamModel is identical as it is now a shared resource. I'm new with Blazor and I'm sure I'm missing something but could do with some direction or help.

```
private async Task FetchTeamData()
{
        try
        {
            List<TeamModel> teams;
            teams = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<TeamModel>>("http://localhost:50663/api/team");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Always blowing up with Children could not be evaluated here.
        }
}
```

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetAllTeams()
{
    List<TeamModel> teams = _teamRepository.GetAllTeams();

    return Ok(teams);
}
```

Edit:
Well I've narrowed it down to being something wrong with the way the project is reading that API. I can call other hosted APIs fine. I'm not sure if its because its localhost or some other issue, but none of the localhost API methods will call properly I always get the same response from it.

Comment: hm strange, i'd expect it to work. might you try getting TeamModel as an array? so like `GetFromJsonAsync<TeamModel[]>`, to avoid breaking the code you might just append `.ToList()`

Comment: I did try this already, I had the same thought as per the examples I've found on the web however end up with the same result. Even if I just grab the JSON as a string it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem, it's a CORS issue. Just add in startup.cs of your API server something like this

```
app.UseCors(policy => 
    policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5000", "https://localhost:5001")
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .WithHeaders(HeaderNames.ContentType));
```

Source: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/blazor/common/samples/3.x/BlazorWebAssemblySample/Pages/CallWebAPI.razor